# How can I directly send a form to a email address through iOS app?

Tags: swift4, swift5

I want to send a email directly from a iOS app to a email address.

I'm trying to integrate this package, but the package is unable to install.
https://github.com/onevcat/Hedwig

I need to send a form as a email.

Answer (score 0):

1) add `MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate` in your class delegate

add the following code in a func

```
  let composeVC = MFMailComposeViewController()
    composeVC.mailComposeDelegate = self
    // Configure the fields of the interface.
    composeVC.setToRecipients([email ?? ""])
    composeVC.setPreferredSendingEmailAddress(someEmail ?? "")
//        composeVC.setSubject("Message Subject")
    composeVC.setMessageBody("Checking", isHTML: false)
    // Present the view controller modally.
    self.present(composeVC, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Then Add this function to go back to app when email view dismiss

```
    func mailComposeController(_ controller: MFMailComposeViewController,
                           didFinishWith result: MFMailComposeResult, error: Error?) {
    // Check the result or perform other tasks.

    // Dismiss the mail compose view controller.
    controller.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to send an email from the app, you need to show a View (like the MailComposer). Apple wont let you send emails in the background. The user needs to know that you're sending an email. *Hedwig* seems to work, but for server side.

Quote annotation from Hedwig's site:

> Can I use it in iOS? At this time Swift Package Manager has no support
>   for iOS, watchOS, or tvOS platforms. So the answer is no. But this
>   framework is not using anything only in iOS (like UIKit), so as soon
>   as Swift Package Manager supports iOS, you can use it there too.